# Healthcare communication standards for web based applications?

Tags: standards

hello i am going to develop a web based application that is Electronic Health records one of the constraints is the my system should follow a communication standard that is complied by most of such type of applications.

i go for a standard known as HL7 health level 7 but i am bit confused!

problem is i can't differentiate between the two standards (HL7 and CDA 2.0) may be they have some relationship with each other but i am not sure about it any one can help me|????

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Health Level 7 (HL7) is a non-profit organization providing a framework and related standards for exchange and retrieval of electronic health information. Their standards relate to documents, messaging, applications and concepts.

CDA 2.0 is one of their standards relating to clinical documents such as discharge summaries and progress notes.

Comment: ohhh but what about this link where i find CDA 2.0 is a part of HL7
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_Document_Architecture

Comment: Yes, it is part of HL7's sets of standards. I'm not sure where the confusion is?

Comment: If you are interested in working in healthcare, consider joining the [Healthcare Industry stack exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41370/healthcare-industry?referrer=0FgbVsKaId7Z_15aCbzplg2) proposal on Area 51.